# Add each value from JSON query as it is returned

Tags: jquery, json

I created this query to basically send sets of latitudes and longitudes for store locations one at a time to get a count of how many customer addresses are within a certain distance from the store (10 miles). What I get returned is one number for each store. I set this up initially to just append all the counts(numbers) to a div just to see if I could get it working. It works now, but what I really want to do is add each of the numbers together one at a time as they are returned to get a grand total. I've tried several different .each statements and none seem to work.

Here's the code to append all the numbers:

```
$.getJSON('<QUERY URL HERE>').done(function (data) {
 var coors = data.rows.map(function (row) {
    return [row[1],row[2]];
});

$.each(coors, function (index,value) {
   var key='API KEY'
          var table ='TABLE NUMBER'
           var sql = "SELECT COUNT() from " + table +
              " WHERE ST_INTERSECTS(coordinates,CIRCLE(LATLNG("+value+"), 16093 ))";
              url = "https://www.googleapis.com/fusiontables/v1/query?key=" + encodeURIComponent(key) + "&sql=" + encodeURIComponent(sql) + '&callback=?';

$.getJSON(url, function (data) {
$('#info2').append(data.rows ? data.rows[0] : 0,",");
          });
```

This give me the following in #info2:

```
30,285,61,326,609,14,13,30,24,87,24,77,16,165,16,925,152,383,391,253,9,75,16,16,467,72,678,523,193,870,161,422,333,
```

So, rather than display each of these numbers, I just want to add them together and display the total. Thoughts on the best way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

`Array.reduce` seems the better choice here, supposing `data.rows` is an `Array` of `Number`s

```
$('#info2').append(data.rows.reduce(function(total, currentNum){
   return total + currentNum;
}, 0));
```

Comment: And now the one million dollar question: Why not simply `return total + currentNum;`?

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question... he is sending a request on each iteration, and he needs to get the sum of all their results.. the asynchronous stuff ;)

Comment: I'm guessing there's a problem with my data (i.e., data.rows) doesn't appear to be an array. When I tried your solution, I just had a bunch of 0 inserted into the list of numbers. EDIT: I appears that data.rows are returned as strings. I can parseInt, and assign that to a variable, but your function won't accept the variable.

Comment: @jonmrich then what is it?

Comment: It's just a number for each iteration. A single value and that's it. It's a string now, but I can change that with parseInt. There's no array format like [8,232]. It's just 232 for each iteration. (for example)

Comment: @jonmrich can you create a jsfiddle?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67991/discussion-between-jonmrich-and-amit-joki).